# MUI Checkbox - only one selected at a time

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, radio-button, radio-group

I need to make a checkbox work as a radio button. I have a Checkbox component that returns a MUI checkbox along with some description. The parent component will render 3:

```
return (
<>
    <CheckboxComponent />
    <CheckboxComponent />
    <CheckboxComponent />
</>
)
```

I am guessing that I will need to control the state from the parent component, something like this:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([false, false, false])
```

I was trying to pass an ID prop to each of the checkbox components to identify which one was clicked and therefore set the state of the other ones to false but can't make it work.

Is there any better way to handle such scenario? I looked through MUI docs to see whether I could use radio buttons but make them look as checkmarks but did not find anything.

*Note:

1. It must be checkmarks, can't change them to simply use the radio buttons
2. There must be child components for checkmarks and they cannot be a part of a parent component

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array for the state, you can try using an index to keep the state.

Then use the state to determine whether or not a checkbox is checked.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(-1)
return (
   <>
      <Checkbox checked={state === 0} />
      <Checkbox checked={state === 1} />
      <Checkbox checked={state === 2} />
   </>
);
```